# The events calendar wordpress plugin - sidebar menu customization

Tags: wordpress

**This is solved**

I have a pro version of [this plugin](https://theeventscalendar.com/) .This is my second day with the plugin and I dont have any clue on  how to create a side bar menu something like this : 
[image] .

I come to know from the official site of plugin that we need to customize template files , but because of lack of time I need help from community on how should i go about developing this Upcoming events side bar . I dont have any code to share as of now , will update my question with further updates meanwhile .

Comment: if you have a pro version, they have a dedicated support system [here](https://theeventscalendar.com/support/). It is very hard to answer questions related to pro versions of plugins as many users don't have access to it

Comment: thanks sohrab , i figured it out ..will post an answer soon

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the name of functionality what I am looking for is the **List Widget** , after figuring that out I was able to find the related documentation on [here](https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/configuring-the-list-widget/)

[image]